# Set timeout on directive that measures height of a div with ng-cloak

Tags: angularjs

I've started to experience the predicted behaviour on page load, when I set directive that measures height of a div.

Using that directive I get a height of my div for accordion purpose animation, when is opening. When I don't have set `max-height` on the div, than the animation doesn't work. In template it looks like this:

```
<div class="accordion-wrapper" ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showProductInfo }" log-height style="max-height: {{readyHeight}}px;">
```

The measured div had flicker effect so I add the [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) to that div. With it, as a page loads it also loads the css property `display:none !imporant` for that particular directive.

So in this case, the code I use to get a height always return blank respond, because of that css property.

**Current code to measure heights**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var rootApp = angular.module('rootApp', ['ngMaterial','ngAnimate']);

rootApp.directive('logHeight', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.Math = window.Math;
            scope.notReadyHeight = element.prop('offsetHeight');
            scope.value = 0;
            scope.readyHeight = scope.Math.min(scope.value + scope.notReadyHeight);
        }
    };
});
</script>
```

Now, I'm thinking to fire this directive after html template is rendered. I don't quiet understand How could I implement that `$timeout` into this directive, that would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$timeout` to delay execution of the code until the browser rendered the div:

```
$timeout(function()
{            
    scope.notReadyHeight = element.prop('offsetHeight');
    scope.value = 0;
    scope.readyHeight = scope.Math.min(scope.value + scope.notReadyHeight);
}, 200);
```

The 200ms delay may be larger or smaller, depending on the browser rendering delay. But 200ms should work.

But i cannot understand what you want to do in this directive.

By the way, the line

```
scope.readyHeight = scope.Math.min(scope.value + scope.notReadyHeight);
```

is equivalent to

```
scope.readyHeight = scope.value + scope.notReadyHeight;
```

Comment: Note you probably don't even need a 200ms time out.  It's almost certainly a matter of waiting for the digest cycle to complete, so you can either omit the delay completely, or set it to 0ms.

Comment: @ul90 I've updated the question about What I want to do with this directive. But anyway, I was playing with your answer and I always have got `0px`.

Answer (score 0):

Include the timeout inside of your `link` function:

```
rootApp.directive('logHeight', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.Math = window.Math;
            scope.notReadyHeight = element.prop('offsetHeight');
            scope.value = 0;
            $timeout(function() {
                scope.readyHeight = scope.value + scope.notReadyHeight;
            }, 0);
        }
    };
});
```

Note that the `$timeout` is useful because even with a 0ms delay, it waits for the digest loop to complete, so any sizing, rendering, `ng-cloak`-ing, etc. should be complete by the time it runs.

Also note you want to be careful with your dependency injection.  If you minify the above code, it may break.  You should use this style instead:

```
rootApp.directive('logHeight', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    // code goes here
}]);
```

Comment: I've used the last option you've provided and I got `0px`. Than I've tried the first one, the same.  Than I was thinking whether we need to set `$timeout` before first scope, because ng-cloak would be called before the `@timeout`. So in this case applied values of `scope.notReadyHeight = 0` +  `scope.value = 0` to `scope.readyHeight` would always be `0`?